# How do I fill the gap between the footer and the main body of text with more text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, footers

If you look at the footer on the left of the attached image you will notice that the gap between the text and the footer is huge compared to the page on the right. I want to fill this large gap with another line (or two) of text.

Note: 
-The margin size has to be exactly 2.5cm so that can't change.
-I don't want to decrease the spacing between the text and the footer. I just want to fill the gap with more text; like the page on the right.

It's a law assignment that has to be less than a certain number of pages and it's driving me mad.

Thanks in advance for any help.

> [image: Screenshot Of Document Footer]

Comment: Change the paragraph formatting, in particular look at keep with following.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your response. How do I do this? I'm using Word 2016.

Comment: Format > paragraph > Line and Page Breaks > Check Keep Lines Together

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what the top of page 9 looks like, but I suspect this actually has to do with the Widow/Orphan control setting on the Line and Line Breaks tab in the Paragraph dialog box. You could try clearing the check box if it's selected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is actually not a large gap, due to the double spacing on lines. It doesn't look to me like another line would fit and still give enough room between the last line, and the footer.

After having said that, check to make sure you don't have an accidental extra carriage return IN your header, and check your line spacing. It might be a good idea to take the total page size (subtract header and footer), divide that by the line spacing, and try to make that an even number. I think what you've got is basically a half line, and nothing will fit in a half line (Half line, as you're at double spacing).

Also, check your widow and orphan control. If need be, highlight the next paragraph, go to the paragraph settings, go to Line and Page Breaks, and play with 'keep together with next' and/or widow and orphan settings (Let me know if you need a screenshot to get there).